# Delete Rows with Dates Between 2012 and 08/02/2014

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all the rows where dates in Column "X" are between year 01/01/2012 and 08/01/2014. I tried looking for a dummy code but couldn't find any.

Comment: You need to loop the rows backwards, then if year(x)=2012 or year(x)=2013 or x< dateserial(2014,1,8) then rows(x).entirerow.delete

Comment: I have written a code and it works too, however, takes forever to complete.

`Cells(1, 27) = "8/2/2014"
Cells(1, 27).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Columns("X:X").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Dim endrow As Integer
On Error Resume Next
endrow = Sheets("PO Working").Range("X50000").End(xlUp).Row
Searchdate = Sheets("PO Working").Range("AA1").value
For i = endrow To 1 Step -1
tdate = Cells(i, 24).value
If IsDate(tdate) = True And tdate < Searchdate Then
Cells(i, 24).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i`

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
for r = activesheet.cells(activesheet.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row to 1 step -1

    if year(activesheet.rows(r).cells(1,"x").value)=2013 then
          activesheet.rows(r).entirerow.delete
    end if


next r
```

not test this, but this is how i'd do it, if it couldnt be done via filtering through VBA maybe?

Comment: You have given me the code for a year that is 2013". This will only remove the rows where year is 2013. I need all rows to be deleted where date is less than "8/2/2014".

Comment: Well put a bit of effort in then, i've said earlier what you need to do.

Comment: I did modify the code and it is working but again my problem it is taking forever to complete. There are more than 13000 rows. I have turn the calculation off to speed up the process but still it is taking too much time.

Comment: you could search the column for values that are smaller than the date 8/2/2014 (Cells.Values < 08/02/2014) then just delete every row where such a date is found in (Cells.Row.Delete)

Answer (score 1):

It's no wonder that this takes forever. It has to calculate the whole if statement for 13000 cells.

Is this a one time only action? If yes, why dont you mark the whole table, then sort the data for column x. If column x is formatted as data then it should sort it normally (increasing or decreasing as you wish, I'd do it with increasing values) and then you can press ctrl+f, enter 08/01/2014 > press search and it should jump to the first line with this date. You can just delete everything above it. No need for codes that take for ever :)